# Determining if Signalr Backplane is Necessary

Tags: websocket, signalr

I'm having trouble figuring out if using a Signalr backplane will be necessary for my scenario. Unfortunately I can't get the test environment I need to test this out myself so I'm coming here ;)

In my scenario we are using signalr to communicate with specific clients (using the connection id) FROM a server application, which is a windows service. When a client visits a certain page, we hook into the signalr OnConnected event and register the user to receive notifications in our data store. Right now we store the connection id, the IP of the server they are coming from, and some other application specific information.

When the server process runs and determines it needs to send a message to a client, it constructs a proxy using the IP that was captured when the client connected/subscribed (the proxy is cached, btw) and sends the message.

This is working fine now. However, I am concerned this will not work in a load balanced scenario. I'm thinking if web sockets are used no problem, but let's say it falls back to long-polling. Couldn't this happen:

- User A visits the page and registers via signalr from web server X with IP 1.1.1.1
- Another long polling request is made from user A, but it goes through web server Y with IP 2.2.2.2
- The server process runs and determines it needs to send a message, but it uses the IP of the server the user connected with - 1.1.1.1
- The message can not be sent to the client

Am I way off with this line of thinking? I am trying to avoid a backplane as each of the scaleout options presents an issue for us.

Comment: Anybody out there......?

Comment: If your hub is hosted with a load balanced setup then you will need a backplane

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is Yes , you will always need a backplane in a load balanced environment

The longer version, you have 2 servers Server A and B load balanced . The user  connects to A , The user can disconnect voluntary or by network time out , or by signalR refresh (there are several bugs open regarding this it is a certain regression but can still re merge in future release irrelevant which communication is used) but basically the user can sometimes find him self "suddnely" connected to server B. And now server A will not be able to send data to the user .

Comment: I figured as much. Thanks for the confirmation!  However, I am storing the server address the user "registers" from. So, if the user reconnects to server B, I will save that server address and communicate with the hub from my .net client using that address.  Wouldn't that handle the issue?

One not so great temporary solution for me might be to host the hub on our application server (just one instance).

Comment: Yes that will work ,  but then you will have to have Hub communicate with each other ,  and what happens when the original Hub is recycled under the load balancer ?  but any way essantly you are trying to achieve a feature that SignalR has already implemented . why dont you want to use  a backplane ?

Comment: It's not that I don't, it's that none of the provided options will work for our scenario. Accessing the DB directly from the web cluster is out of the question, Redis is out of the questions (too bad), as is Azure.

Comment: have you thought having a dedicated SQL server for  this ? , depending on your expected load . SQL server express edition might be good enough

Comment: Yes I have, and will probably try to push this option. Or just use Redis and not tell anyone ;) Thanks